# XF + DryIoc: Unable to select single public constructor from implementation type Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage

Tags: prism, dryioc

I just created a XF + Prism + DryIoc project using Prism template in VS2017.
I updated an app XF and Prism to latest:

- XF: 2.5.0.121934
- Prism: 7.0.0.336-pre

Without adding any of more code (except fixing breaking changes with latest Prism 7), when running the app I get:

> Unable to select single public constructor from implementation type
>   Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage

I search a bit and I found https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/889 but issue is supposed to be resolved with latest DryIoc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed and is available in the latest CI build on MyGet.

Answer (score 2):

As Brian indicated this was fixed and is on MyGet. This was actually a bit of a regression that was caused by our move to unify the API and abstract the IOC containers in Prism 7. You'll notice this was reported:

- [Issue 1304](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1304)
- [Issue 1309](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1309)
- [Issue 1311](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1311)

And was fixed in [PR 1305](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/pull/1305). The fix is available in [7.0.0.340-ci](https://www.myget.org/feed/prism/package/nuget/Prism.DryIoc.Forms) or later.